# Python cli calculator bug with input

Tags: python-3.x

Here is my code,

```
def divide():
# if x is not an int or float, run the input function again...
x = input("Enter a number to divide. ")

while True:
    try:
        if x != int(x) or x != float(x):
            x = input("Error! Please try again, enter a number to divide. ")
        else:
            break
    except ValueError:
        print("value error")
        break

y = input("Enter a number to divide " + x + " by. ")

while True:
    try:
        if y != int(y) or y != float(y):
            y = input("Error! Please try again, enter a number to divide " + x + " by. ")
        else:
            break
    except ValueError:
        print("value Error")
        break

if x == int(x) or y == int(y):
    x = int(x)
    y = int(y)
else:
    x = float(x)
    y = float(y)

divideAns = x / y
divide.result = str(x) + " / " + str(y) + " = " + str(divideAns)
return divide.result
```

So my issue is when I run the divide function, let's say a careless user just typed nonsense, I get errors. Unless I explicitly type an integer I get errors, I want the user to be able to anything that is not a number or float and get a custom error. Second, I want the user to be able to divide both integers and floats. I feel like my mind is going in the right direction with this, but I just can't seem to make it work right. I found another post talking about just converting everything to a float, however I would like to keep, ints ints, and floats floats. Is this possible? If so what is the best approach to this.

Comment: My only issue with this is from what I understand, `input()` always returns a string, correct?

Comment: that's true, your first input is unprotected, ie no try

Answer (score 0):

Write a function like this which tries to convert the user input to a int or float and raises an exception if this is not possible.

```
class InvalidUserInput(Exception):
    '''
    Signals that user did not enter a valid value
    '''
    pass

def float_or_int_from_str(inp: str):
    '''
    Reads string and tries to extract int or float
    from it. If this is not possible, raises 
    InvalidUserInput
    '''
    try:
        return int(inp)
    except ValueError:
        pass

    try:
        return float(inp)
    except ValueError:
        pass

    # No matches so far -> raise Exception
    raise InvalidUserInput("'{}' is neither a float nor an int".format(inp))
```

You can then use this function to enforce valid user inputs:

```
user_input = float_or_int_from_str(input("Enter a number to divide. "))
```

An alternative to using those `try: except:` constructs would be to actually parse the user input yourself using regular expressions. Could look like this:

```
import re

def float_or_int_from_str(inp: str):
    '''
    Reads string and tries to extract int or float
    from it. If this is not possible, raises 
    InvalidUserInput
    '''
    if re.match(r"[+-]?[0-9]+", inp) is not None:
        return int(inp)
    elif re.match(r"[+-]?[0-9]*\.[0-9]*(e[+-]?[0-9]+)?", inp) is not None:
        return float(inp)
    else:
        raise InvalidUserInput("...")
```

If you want to enforce the user to use floats or ints consistently, you could add something like

```
if not type(a) is type(b):
    raise InvalidUserInput("...")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple issues.

Your two inputs are outside of `try` blocks.  This will make the function fail.
You also have to take into account that all inputs are taken as string.  You need to convert them to `float` (can deal with float vs null later) to test that they are numeric.

```
def divide():
    # if x is not an int or float, run the input function again...
    while True:
        try:
            x = float(input('que numero'))
            break
        except:
            print('that\'s no numero!')

    while True:
        try:
            y = float(input('que numero'))
            break
        except:
            print('that\'s no numero!')

    return x/y if x/y != int(x/y) else int(x/y)
```

Answer (score 0):

## This will do the job for you...

I don't know why you want to keep ints ints and floats floats, they're both numbers just one has a decimal point... Never the less I'll do it!

```
def divide():
    x = False
    while not x:
        try:
            x = float(input("Enter a number to divide: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a float or an integer, not a string..    .")

    # This checks if it's an int or a float.
    x = str(x).split('.')
    if x[1] == '0':
        x = int(x[0])
    else:
        x = float(".".join(x))

    y = False
    while not y:
        try:
            y = float(input("Enter a number to divide %s by: " % x))
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a float or an integer, not a string...")
        if y == 0:
            y = False


    y = str(y).split('.')

    if y[1] == '0':
        y = int(y[0])
    else:
        y = float(".".join(y))

    divideAns = x / y
    result = str(x) + " / " + str(y) + " = " + str(divideAns)

    return result
```